# How do I get the hexadecimal representation of $foo in Perl?

Tags: perl, hex

Given the variable `$foo` containing binary data, how do I get the hexadecimal representation of `$foo` in Perl?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If `$foo` is a string containing arbitrary data, use [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html):

```
my $hex = unpack('H*', $foo);
```

If it's just an integer, use [sprintf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html):

```
my $hex = sprintf('%x', $foo); # Or %X if you want upper-case letters
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ perldoc -f hex
…
To present something as hex,
look into "printf", "sprintf", or "unpack".
```

==>

```
$hex = sprintf("%x", $foo);
```